# Сравнение дробей

Tags: c++

```
  if(8.3-8==3.0/10)
      cout<<1;
  else
      cout<<2;
```

Почему программа выдает 2?

Comment: Использование типов с плавающей запятой всегда влечет за собой погрешность.